# update an element of an array in mongo collection based on a condition met by another element in the same array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Below is my collection.

```
{
'_id': ObjectId('603fd4575250717d17aba89e'),
'user_id': 19,
'items': [
{

'price': 5,
'id': '342566b0d5f14117a228d8b17f215c4a'
},


 {


 'price': 5,
 'id': '09e12c647fdf4c409e934eac23c73789'
}
],

  }
```

I need to update the price for the element with the id 09e12c647fdf4c409e934eac23c73789, its current value is 5 and I need to update it to 6, may I know the query for the same please.

I tried with the below query and it did not work.

```
a = db.sample_collection.update_one({"items.$.id": "09e12c647fdf4c409e934eac23c73789"}, 
{"$set": {"items.$price": 6}})
```

Can someone help me on the correct query please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update query should look like this:

```py
a = db.sample_collection.update_one({"items.id": "09e12c647fdf4c409e934eac23c73789"}, { "$set": { "items.$.price": 6 }})
```

This is an example of [updating a document in an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array). When performing an update, the [positional operator, $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update) should only appear in the update document, not the query document.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$elemMatch` to find the array index and `$` operator to update the data of that index accordingly

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {"items":{ "$elemMatch":{"id":"09e12c647fdf4c409e934eac23c73789"} }},
    { $set: { "items.$.price": 6 } }
)
```